# Need help decyphering message

Tags: encryption, keys

THEIR DIFFERENCE WILL REMAIN, LONG AFTER THEY ARE DEAD
Dear Friend,
IV IV 12 8 14 - 19 14 18 9 13 IV I C C 9 17 IV 17 12 IV 8 14 IV 7 F 14 IV 7 19 D IV 12 15 F 19 E IV 8 17 IV 7 12 15 F 19 13 17 9 E IV 8 17 IV 12 IV 17 15 F 19 IV 7 IV 8 14 IV II 9 17 14 D 9
Only one of them will take you to the finish line and unlock the treasure.
Add to the other one and he will show something important. Remember him, he holds the key.
erugbzqanet lz sb lebzrz av

Can someone help decyphering the above? I thought Ceaser first, but I am lost.